# Accessing Wiki Data that's similar to the actual wiki page

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api, wikidata, wikidata-api

wikidata url: `https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q254138&format=json&props=claims`

The part I'm currently looking at is genre, which is `P136`. This only contains one genre in it, and that ID links to "heavy metal music" `Q38848`

Looking on the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slipknot_(band) there are three different genres. Why do I not have 3 genres in this property?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is because that information simply doesn't exist in wikidata

Comment: Correct. In a way, just 'heavy metal' is the genre, as 'nu metal' and 'alternative metal' are both (sort of) subgenres of that.